# How to implement command-line variables in Xtext

Tags: parsing, xtext

I want my Domain specific language (DSL) to accept command-line arguments as variables like in bash scripts. For example: A user might issue a command `runMyDSL myDslFile.dsl -args 10 15` or `runMyDSL myDslFile.dsl -nvargs arg1=10 arg2=15`. I would like to capture these values into variables $1, $2 for first command or $arg1, $arg2 for second command. These variables can then be treated as any other read-only variables in my DSL:

```
val someVariable = $1
```

Since I am new to xtext/parser field, I am looking for best practices people follow for dealing with this situation. For simplicity, let's assume, I am only working on simplified DSL that does addition (based on Expression Language described in http://blog.efftinge.de/2010/08/parsing-expressions-with-xtext.html):

```
Expression : Variable '+' Variable;
Variable: ('val' ID '=' INT) | CommandLineVariable;
CommandLineVariable: ??;
```

Answer (score 0):

My first idea for that would be the following:

1.) parse the DSL file and get access to the AST, store the refence in any locally definded variable of the corresponding EClass.

2.) Use the 'MyDslFactory' class to create a new 'Variable' instance, set a value, given by the command line and put it somewhere into the AST.

To do that you should define attribute names in you 'Variable' Parser Rule:

```
Variable: 'val' name=ID '=' value=INT;
```

'Variable' creation would look like this (more or less):

```
Variable newVar = MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE.createVariable();
newVar.setName(args[2].split("=")[0]);
newVar.setValue(new Integer(args[2].split("=")[1]));
```

Then you put it into the AST and with the modified AST you could either create a temporary DSL file which is then processed as before or you process the AST directly.